# Redirect user to log in page whenever the user tries to access a page set as Page Requires Authentication in the Authentication field Apex Oracle

Tags: oracle-apex

As the title suggests, i want to transfer the user to for example, log in page whenever the user is not authenticated and tries to access a page set to Page Requires Authentication. I don't want to show the No Access error page or w/e it was, instead i want the log in form to show. How do i achieve this?

I was thinking of setting authorization scheme that whenever the user tries to access the page, in the error message of the authorization scheme a link to show that leads to log in page, but i don't want this even though it seems like a decent alternative.

Answer (score 1):

On the public page, create a component (link/button/...) that redirects to a page that requires authentication (not authorization). Put a serverside condition on the component of type "user is the public user" if you only want this component to be visible if the user is not authenticated. This will force the user to log in after clicking on the component.

No authorization schemes should be needed to achieve this functionality.

Comment: thank you for the answer, but i already know this and you kinda missed the point of my question. What i want to do is, for example, a user manually opens a link of a blog post (somewhere was posted but someone), but the user cannot see the blog post because the users needs to be logged in and when trying the access the blog post, instead of seeing the error page or the blog post, the user should automatically be redirected to some page (to the login form for example). How do i achieve this automatic redirection without user clicking any button nor a link?!

Comment: If a user accesses an apex page (I assume that "blog post" you are referring to is an apex page) and he needs to be authenticated then he will be prompted to log in and not get an error message. What am I missing ? "No access" is not an authentication error, it is an authorization error - could it be you're mixing those 2 up ?

Comment: The fastest way to get this solved is probably to create a workspace for this isue on apex.oracle.com, create an empty app where you illustrate the issue and share the credentials

Comment: i think there is no need to make a new application, even though if that suits you i can do it. the error i get is the following: "You are not authorized to view this application, either because you have not been granted access, or your account has been locked. Please contact the application administrator.

Access denied by Application security check".

How do i get rid of showing this error all the time and redirect to some other page in the app?

Comment: Error indicates there is an authorization scheme preventing the user from accessing the page. Can be at application level or page level. You control how you want the app to be secured ... hard to give more details. You have not explained how your authentication or authorization is setup... that is why I suggested creating a quick app...

Comment: The application uses custom authentication function that checks whether a user is in the users' table in database. The authorization is not touched yet and is completely default as apex sets it up when a new application is created. I plan to fiddle with the authorization in the complete end when i finish making all the pages of the application.

Comment: I'm assuming the issue is with the default authorization schemes that are created. If you create an app on apex.oracle.com where you can show the exact problem you're facing I'm happy to take a look.

Comment: Hey! Sorry for the late reply as i was busy with life and work. I managed to fix it, in the app definition -> security -> authorization, the scheme was set to Reader Rights for some reason. I changed it to Not Reader Rights and now it works as intended asking me to log in. However now i don't know how to change the redirection link to log in page (i had my log in page alias set to login while this redirects me to page with alias login9999, i guess i gotta have my login page alias set to login9999 all the time).

BTW tnx for the time spent to help me, i really appreciate it! <3

Comment: No need to send user to login page manually. Just expose the link to a protected page. APEX will then redirect user to the login page